# Set default java in .bashrc

Tags: java, default

By default my ubuntu system is installed with the following java version:

```
java version "1.7.0_25"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.10) (7u25-2.3.10-1ubuntu0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

If I type `which java` it tells me `/usr/bin/java`.

Now, I have just installed Oracle's Java from their website and have unpacked it inside the directory: `opt/local`

How do I make the default Java start from `opt/local` so that I am using Oracle Java instead of OpenJDK? Is this something I need to auto-configure inside my bashrc?
`
Thanks, and if you need more information let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu's [alternative command management](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/update-alternatives.8.html) will be helpful here I think.

It's basically organized this way

```
generic link(e.g. /usr/bin/java) -> buffer link(e.g. /etc/alternatives/java) -> actual command or executable (e.g. /opt/jdk/java)
```

So you can update the buffer link so that it points to your choice of actual command/executable and still use the generic link to get the job done everywhere as before 
<sub>(of course assuming both commands provides proper functionality ;)</sub>.

[Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java#Manual_method) is a nice guide to update JVM of your choice through `update-alternatives` command. So do the following

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/opt/local/jdk-xx.xx/bin/java" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/opt/local/jdk-xx.xx/bin/javac" 1
```

You can go on and update the java browser plugin and web-start plugin too as mentioned in the guide. Then choose the java of your choice by

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

Comment: This will work if you did the manual installation from their site.  Honestly, though, I would have used the webupd8team's Java PPA which would have automatically updated java alternatives.

Comment: OP says he unpacked it in `/opt/local`, so most probably he downloaded the tar.gz package I guess.

Comment: I put that comment there so that next time people won't have to deal with this.  Besides, Oracle has already said OpenJDK is a suitable equivalent in Linux for their Java, and therefore they aren't going to be updating Java for Linux very much.

Comment: @ThomasW. no problem, it was an useful addition.

Comment: How will I know which java version is being used now? If I use the `which` command it still tells me `/usr/bin/java`

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus `which` will show you the first `java` it finds while following the directories mentioned in `PATH` environment variable in that order, which is `/usr/bin/java`. (`ls -l /usr/bin/java` will show you this link order). use `sudo update-alternatives --config java` to know which `java` executables are recognized and currently used by your system.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing `update-alternatives --config java` and then follow the prompts to change the default Java environment.

Comment: it does not see the java that I installed in `/opt/local`

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus How did you install Java?  With their autoextracting .run file?

Comment: I unpacked a tar file into `/opt/local`

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus yeah that explains the situation, their tarball does not automatically configure the system.